# Does the Youtube developer API and/or video player allow you to play self hosted videos from the Youtube video player?

Tags: html, video, youtube

I'm trying to evaluate different video players for a self hosted web app I'm working on. The Youtube player has a lot of the functionality I'm after, but I can't tell if it will allow for me to play videos on my own server, or if I need to use it with just Youtube video servers. Here is the link to the developer site I was looking at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started.

What would be helpful is the answer to this question and a link to resources where this information was found, so that I can hopefully explore related questions as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the youTube player can only be used to play content hosted by youTube.
As you will see from the [API Description](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Selecting_Content_to_Play) the only way to specific a video is by it's youTube videoID (or by selecting a youTube Playlist, user or other grouping) - there is no option to provide an externally hosted URL.

There are many very good player frameworks out there but without knowing your specific requirements it's going to be hard to suggest an option (and SO is more for answering programming questions than providing opinions - only you will know which is the best fit for your project)